# Azure deployment slots RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, rbac

I need to give different level of access to different users (or groups) on an Azure WebApp and its deployment slots.

1. If I give a user access to only a deployment slot, he cannot see it on the Azure Management Portal.
2. If I give a user access as "Reader" to the entire web app, he can change application settings (it was not supposed to happen)
3. If I give a user access as "Reader" to the entire web app and as "Owner" to a particular slot, he can change application settings and he can swap the LIVE app (both they were not supposed to happen)

Someone can explain to me how to give "Owner" permission only to a deployment slot and not to the whole application? 
Thanks!

Comment: If that is the case it is almost certainly a bug you should raise with MS (and quite a significant one at that) - I'm curious to replicate it, but don't have time at the moment.

Comment: Linking to same question on MSDN for cross reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99037e3b-5306-4542-9c7c-ee2cd5719090/azure-deployment-slots-rbac?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll tackle the 3 questions below

#### If I give a user access to only a deployment slot, he cannot see it on the Azure Management Portal

It's a portal bug (it will get fixed). Luckily, there is a workaround which is not too painful:

- While logged on as the owner, go to the slot in the portal. The URL will look like this:

`https://portal.azure.com/#resource/subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{AppName}/slots/{SlotName}`

- Copy the URL and send it to your user
- They'll then be able to go straight to the slot, even though they can't access the Web App. They'll even be able to 'pin' it to their dashboard, so they can easily find it next time without having to go back to the link.

#### If I give a user access as "Reader" to the entire web app, he can change application settings

It just looks that way due to another Portal bug, but they really can't. e.g.

- they won't be able to see any of the current settings
- if they change something, it says the Save is successful, but in fact nothing happens

The Portal team is aware of it and will address it. But security wise, it is harmless.

#### If I give a user access as "Reader" to the entire web app and as "Owner" to a particular slot, he can swap the LIVE app

That sounds like a bug and I will report it. Good catch!

The good news is that if you don't give them Reader access to the Web App, they won't be able to do this. So just use the technique I described in the first question, and everything should work fine for your scenario

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I already found the complete link workaround, but your explanation helped me a lot to define the correct user management strategy! And it saves me a lot of time for further investigation!

Comment: "If I give a user access as "Reader" to the entire web app and as "Owner" to a particular slot, he can swap the LIVE app" - this has been fixed. Thanks for reporting this!